# How do I place a call from my original phone number if Google Voice is the default handler?

Tags: cyanogenmod, phone-app, google-voice

I have a AT&T Galaxy SII running CM9 and primarily use my Google Voice number and all of the Google Voice integration on the phone. I'd like to be able to place a call using my native (non-GV) number. Is there any way that I can place a call *without* using Google Voice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you mean you still want to use GV services, but with your phones' native number? Or do you mean you want to completely circumvent using GV sometimes?

**If you meant still use GV, but with your native number:**

Voice->Settings->This phone's number

Then just choose your phone's native number (you're still using GV services, but caller-id will show your phone's number, not your GV number).

**If you meant completely circumvent GV and use your phone as if GV wasn't installed:**

Voice->Settings->Making calls.

choose either `Do not use Google Voice to make any calls` or `Ask every time I make a call`

Comment: It was the second option I was looking for, circumventing GV completely for some calls. I had been hunting through the system settings and dialer settings and not finding the proper option. Thanks!